# Reliability test in Likert scale

Tags: likert, reliability

I have found a Likert scale measure in an article for global job satisfaction measure that included three items as follows;

1. All in all I am satisfied with my job,
2. In general, I don't like my job
3. In general I like working here.

The three items had been measured on seven point scale ranging from strongly disagree (1) and strongly agree (7).

My concern: Is the second question has been included for reliability test purpose only and should I delete the item during analysis?

I would really appreciate for any help.

Thank You, 
Regards, 
Reaz.

Comment: Can you clarify your concern? I can't follow the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The second question can be rescored by flipping the answer. After rescoring you could compute Cronbach's alpha for reliability of the items.